# Cannot connect to specific UUID of Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, uuid

I am having trouble connecting to a specific UUID of a Bluetooth device:

```
private void initBt() {
    BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (blueAdapter != null) {
        blueAdapter.enable();
        if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {

            BluetoothDevice device = blueAdapter.getRemoteDevice("B0:00:00:00:00:F3");

            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("0000fff1-0000-0000-0000-00805f9b34fb");
            BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            socket.connect();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        } else {
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("BluetoothAdapter failure");
    }
}
```

I want to get an output stream to this UUID so I can send messages to it.
I got the UUID from the App LightBlue.

I cannot pair the device (and I think I don't have to, if LightBlue can send messages to the UUID without manual pairing).

An IOException is thrown on socket.connect(); stating:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried it with

```
device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

and also double checked that I have all the permissions to do so (Bluetooth, BluetoothAdmin and AccessFineLocation).

Comment: what in your code is not working?

Comment: I get the following error on socket.connect(): `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`

Comment: @FabianSchneider Android studio provides sample projects for Bluetooth functionality. Go to File-> New-> Import Sample. You will see a search bar. Just type in Bluetooth Chat and import the project which you get as result. This project has the code to connect to a specific UUID.

Comment: @SanketMendon thanks, I'll give it a try...

Comment: @SanketMendon I tried it the way the example suggests. the procedure for connecting and sending a message is no different to the code I wrote. Although it still doesn't work. I still get the timeout.